# Adding CSS class into multiple DIVs that have same class selector

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following script which adds CSS class `hidden-mobile` to the targeted div block `sorter-pager` just fine but the page has two div blocks sharing `sorter-pager` and CSS class gets only added to one of the div block, not both.

```
if($$('.sorter-pager .pages')[0].empty()) {
    $$('.sorter-pager')[0].addClassName('hidden-mobile');
}
```

How can I make it make it so that CSS class `hidden-mobile` can be added to multiple div blocks with `sorter-pager` selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a prototypesjs guy, but it seems pretty clear you're accessing only the first item in the array with "[0]", hence the class is only being applied to the first ".sorter-pager"  element.

If prototype supports list comprehension methods, use those. Otherwise,manually loop over all ".sorter-pager" items in your array and call "addClassName" individually.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of it being an array but haven't tried manually looping them over. It should do for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only checking the first element in the CSS selector like this

```
if($$('.sorter-pager .pages')[0].empty()) {
```

but you want to add the class name to all the elements that match the next selector, you can easily do it with the `invoke()` method

```
if($$('.sorter-pager .pages')[0].empty()) {
    $$('.sorter-pager').invoke('addClassName','hidden-mobile');
}
```

`invoke()` takes the first parameter as the method name you want to call on all items in the array and an optional number of parameters after that which are passed to the method call

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/invoke/